# Materials for a post War of the Lance campaign

Tags: dnd-3.5e, product-identification, campaign-settings, dragonlance

Soon we will be starting a DragonLance campaign, and we have settled on the post War of Lance, around a year after the official end of the war. The problem I have is that there are barely any materials. There is a timeline in Dragonlance Campaign Setting, and a page of text in War of the Lance, which gives barely any insight.

Are there any setting rulebooks for this period or adventure modules? Alternatively, which books take place during that time?

The campaign is going to take place around a year after the official end of the war (if I recall correctly, from the point where Tanis has killed the lord... Can't recall his name yet). I don't know about the edition, for sure we are playing dnd 3.5, but I don't know how the settings are different in different editions.

Comment: What edition are you planning on using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that depends what you mean by post war of the lance.  There are couple time frames i can think of that fit.

Pre Age of mortals - Same rules as exist in the [Dragonlance Adventures book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0880384522)  These are written circa 1ed-2ed.  The [3rd ED Version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786930861)  I didnt really use I leafed through it and did not see anything useful to me at the time but DL is probably my favorite D&D Setting so I did not really need most of its back grounds. The [4e Version](http://www.dlnexus.com/) is planned but not released yet but DL Nexus has info on it.

[Age of Mortals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1931567107)

There are some good reference material in some of the old Dragon magizines but I do not have references to exactly where.  If you are looking for something more specific let me know I can probably point you in a direction.

[Dragonlance Atlas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0880384484)

This is a great book for the area.  Has good information on a lot of towns and villages.  There are versions for different periods but my version is pre AOM so i dont know if there is a revised with that part.

[Leaves of the Inn of the Last Home](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0880384654)
This is an essential for any true dragonlance collection.  It has good information on different areas (mostly post WOL pre Legends) but more importantly it has the recipe for Otiks spiced potato's... OMG they are as good as promised by the books :p

[History of Dragonlance](http://The%20History%20of%20Dragonlance%3a%20Being%20the%20Notes,%20Journals,%20and%20Memorabilia%20of%20Krynn)
Pretty rare collectable book.  Really just rehashes things from the book but if you are not like me and havent read every dl book then this is a pretty good cliff note type.

The best reference is the books.  Sometimes the contradict (like Sturm fighting draconiains in the preludes) but they add good reference for the area and its people.

Comment: Well, as updated in the main post, I am looking for historic information about the time around a year after the end of war.

Comment: Dragonlance adventures book is designed for campaigns around this time.  While some of the kits need to be updated for 3.5, the setting of the campaign is there.  There were quite a few modules and adventures from this time period in 1-2e days.  Look for DL Adventures from mid-late 1980's to early 90's.  Around 1993 DL sourcebooks took a turn away from this.  I do not know what if any DL Adventures have come out in the last 5 years but I think most of them are set around the end of the age of mortals ~30-40 years after what you want.

Comment: Is there something more specific you are looking for?

Comment: Hm, I am looking for some data about how the people's lives were like at that time - it was after a war, yet its effects are still present. We are planning to start in Solace, so some information about nearby towns and army remnants, possibly about how Qualinesti changed since then. Some details about soon-to-come world shaking events. I will reread ending of Summer Flame to get some more information surely, but I am striving for a good amount of match between by campaign and the canonical story.

Comment: there were lots of adventures but i think most of them were 1st ed.  That was fine for 2nd ed but not really with first.  DLA has a pretty good map. Otherwise i added a few more references.